# Replace observations with specific values in multiple columns

Tags: r, loops, data.table, purrr

I have a dataframe that looks something like this.

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~name,           ~x,  ~y,              ~z,  
  "N/A",           1,   "N/A",           -100, 
  "N A",           3,   "NOt available", -99,
  "N / A",         NA,  "29",              -98,
  "Not Available", -99, "25",              -101,
  "John Smith",    -98, "28",              -1)
```

I would like to use map() and or data.table() to replace all the observations in character variables that are "N/A" or "N A" into `NA`.

I have tried the following but it does not seem to work:

```
chvar <- keep(df,is.character)%>%names()
rpl.NA<- as_mapper(~setDT(df)[.x%in%c("N/A","N A"),.x:=NA])
wrong <- map(chvar,rpl.NA)
```

The issue with this approach is that it produces a list with multiple dataframes in it, rather than simply returning a dataframe.
I have also tried

```
wrong2<-df%>%mutate_at(chvar, list(~replace(., "N/A", NA)))
```

but also this produces an error.

I know that I can do this with `library(naniar)` using the following function

```
na_strings <- c("N/A","N A")
df <- dt %>% replace_with_na_at(.vars = chvar,
                                condition = ~.x %in% na_strings)
```

But this function is very slow and I have to apply it to a large dataset.

Does anyone knows a fast and convenient approach that allows me to apply a function to a selected number of variables on a selected number of observations?

Thanks a lot for your help

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, you could do :

```
library(dplyr)
na_strings <- c("N/A","N A")

df <- df %>% 
         mutate(across(where(is.character), 
                ~replace(.x, .x %in% na_strings, NA)))
```

More larger dataset `data.table` would be efficient :

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[, (chvar) := lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, x %in% na_strings, NA)), 
     .SDcols = chvar]
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can do

```
na_strings <- c("N/A","N A")
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) replace(x, x %in% na_strings, NA))
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple base R option using `replace`

```
replace(df, df == "N/A" | df == "N A", NA)
```

gives

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  name              x y                 z
  <chr>         <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>
1 <NA>              1 <NA>           -100
2 <NA>              3 NOt available   -99
3 N / A            NA 29              -98
4 Not Available   -99 25             -101
5 John Smith      -98 28               -1
```

---

If you have more patterns representing `NA`, you can try the code below for example

```
replace(df,Reduce(`|`, lapply(c("N/A", "N A", "N / A", "Not Available"), `==`, df)),NA)
```